# Keep spaces when using sed command in kornshell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed, spaces, quote

I'm having some trouble with the sed command :
I'd like to replace in a string, a single quote by two single quote

Here's my string :

```
04CA07807800106109XE00187200000081960          NI         0780643442        178'0700
```

I used this sed command to replace the single quote :

```
line=`echo $line | sed "s/'/''/g"`
```

The result is

```
04CA07807800106109XE00187200000081960 NI 0780643442 178''0700
```

As you can see, the single quote is properly replaced by two single quotes.
But I lost all the spaces between each character of my string and I really need to keep them.

Is there a way to keep those spaces with the sed command ? 
I tried with a tr command and i got the same result.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: BTW, `printf '%s\n' "$line"` is actually a bit more correct than `echo "$line"` (which is itself far more correct than `echo $line`) when dealing with arbitrary input -- see the APPLICATION USAGE section of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html

Comment: ...btw, http://shellcheck.net/ would have found this bug for you without needing to get humans involved.

Comment: I wasn't aware of any of this stuff. Duly noted. thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not sed command but your unquoted variable. Use:

```
line=`echo "$line" | sed "s/'/''/g"`
```

Unquoted variable causes [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) which results in multiple parameters to `echo`, resulting in single spaced words.

Comment: "Unquoted variable is trimming all multiple spaces into one."  Kind of.  It undergoes [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) which results in multiple parameters to `echo`, each with no whitespace.

Comment: Thanks, I edited answer with more correct explanation from your comment.

Comment: Well it turns out to be quite easy ! Thank you both for your help :)