# UNIX Replace string without replacing space

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a problem with UNIX script.

```
original_string='AGENT                               UNKNOWN'
replacement=`echo $original_string | sed 's/UNKNOWN/ACTIVE/g'`
echo $replacement
```

The result of this script gives me :

```
AGENT ACTIVE
```

But I want to maintain all the spaces between the characters like:

```
AGENT                               ACTIVE
```

Someone please help.

Comment: Quote your variable: `replacement=$(echo "$original_string" | sed 's/UNKNOWN/ACTIVE/g')`

Comment: The idea is as @anubhava mentioned to use double-quotes around shell variable containing the spaces

Comment: Use quote echo "$replacement" (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306796/keep-spaces-when-using-sed-command-in-kornshell-script)

Comment: It works ... Thanks a lot